# What is the difference between spin_lock and raw_spin_lock()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, synchronization, locking

There is raw variant of each spin lock available in linux kernel, I want to know its usage ? e.g. :

`raw_spin_lock()`, `raw_spin_lock_irqsave()`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

`spin_lock*` functions do the same as `raw_spin_lock*` ones plus, when lock debugging is enabled(CONFIG_DEBUG_LOCK_ALLOC), perform some additional runtime checks for lock operations, such as checks for *deadlock*. These checks are performed by `lockdep` subsystem.

As a rule, **`spin_lock*` functions should be used whenever it is possible**.

Only in rare cases of very tricky locking policy, when `lockdep` can produce false warnings, `raw_spin_lock*` functions can be used.

Also, `raw_*` functions can be preferred to common ones for reduce memory usage or perfomance reasons. But it should be actual time/space *measurements, reflected significant wins* from using these optimizations.

Comment: when lockdep can produce false warnings ? and in -rt normal spin_lock can sleep while raw_spin_lock don't, is it true ?

Comment: How about the PREEMPT_RT patch that supposedly turns spinlocks into rt_mutexes?

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: `PREEMPT_RT` case seems to be described in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39551772/3440745). Is something wrong about it?

Answer (score 9):

The main difference is `spin_lock` variants map to `raw_spin_lock` variants for non-RT whereas if `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT` is set, then they map to `rt_spin_lock` which can sleep.

By decoupling the spin_lock from sleeping vs non-sleeping variations depending on whether we are RT or not, the spin_lock API can be kept consistent across the kernel code.